# Selecting most recent data from table

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a table setup called `item_histories`, which is setup like below.

```
+--------------------------------+
|  id  itemId    date    price   |
+--------------------------------+
| 1    2    2015-01-10    310    |
| 2    2    2015-01-11    318    |
| 3    2    2015-01-12    326    |
| 4    2    2015-01-13    333    |
| 5    2    2015-01-14    335    |
| 6    6    2015-01-10    121598 |
| 7    6    2015-01-11    121598 |
| 8    6    2015-01-12    122666 |
| 9    6    2015-01-13    122666 |
| 10   6    2015-01-14    122666 |
+--------------------------------+
```

I'm trying to select the most recent row for each `itemId`, like so..

```
+--------------------------------+
|  id  itemId    date    price   |
+--------------------------------+
| 5    2    2015-01-14    335    |
| 10   6    2015-01-14    122666 |
+--------------------------------+
```

I'm using `Sequelize` and this is the code I have now.

```
db.itemHistory.findAll({
    attributes: [
        'id',
        'price',
        'itemId',
        [db.Sequelize.fn('max', db.Sequelize.col('date')), 'date']
    ],
    group: ['itemId'],
    limit: 1
}).then(function(histories) {
    console.log(histories);
});
```

Which generated this query, `` SELECT `id`, `price`, `itemId`, max(`date`) AS `test` FROM `item_histories` AS `itemHistory` GROUP BY `itemId` LIMIT 1 ``.

The `` MAX(`date`) `` was my attempt at accomplishing this, but all it does is select the first row, but has a `date` of the most recent.

Comment: The result returned by the MySQL query is expected behavior, because of MySQL has enabled (by default) "extension" to the ANSI standard  GROUP BY behavior. (Other databases would return an error about non-aggregate expressions in the SELECT list that are not included in the GROUP BY.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `(itemId,date)` is UNIQUE in `item_histories`, you can do something like this:

```
 SELECT s.id
      , s.price
      , s.itemid
      , s.date
   FROM ( SELECT q.itemid
               , MAX(q.date) AS max_date
            FROM item_histories q
           GROUP BY q.itemid
        ) r
   JOIN item_histories s
     ON s.itemid = r.itemid  
    AND s.date   = r.max_date
  ORDER BY s.itemid
```

The inline view `r` returns the maximum value of date for *each* itemid. You can run that inline view query separately, to see (and confirm) what it returns.

We use the rows returned from that query as if it was a table. (In MySQL terminology, this is actually called a "derived table".)

We perform a join operation back to the `item_histories` table, to get the rows that have a matching `itemid` and a `date` that matches the `max_date` returned from the inline view.

I noted at the beginning of the answer that this will work as long as `(itemid,date)` is UNIQUE in the table. If that isn't unique, we have the potential of returning multiple rows which have the same `itemid` and `date`.

(Sorry, I can't help you with whatever bizarre syntax Sequelize would need to generate that SQL statement. At the very least, Sequelize should provide some kind of "raw SQL" methods that will let you workaround the limitations.)

(There are other MySQL query patterns that can return an equivalent result.)

---

**FOLLOWUP**

To add a join to `items` table (assuming that `itemid` is a foreign key referencing `item(id)`

Repeating the same query from above, the changes (added lines) are between the comment dash lines.

```
 SELECT s.id
      , s.price
      , s.itemid
      , s.date
 -- ---------------------------------  
      , t.id      AS t_id
      , t.col2    AS t_col2
 -- ---------------------------------   
   FROM ( SELECT q.itemid
               , MAX(q.date) AS max_date
            FROM item_histories q
           GROUP BY q.itemid
        ) r
   JOIN item_histories s
     ON s.itemid = r.itemid  
    AND s.date   = r.max_date
 -- ---------------------------------  
   JOIN items t
     ON t.id = r.itemid
 -- ---------------------------------  
  ORDER BY s.itemid
```

Comment: Thanks, this returns what I would like, however(I know this wasn't in OP), but how would I join ``item_histories.itemId`` to ``items.id``?

Comment: Added followup to demonstrate join to `items` table. (Those comment dash lines aren't necessary, you can remove them. I just did that to highlight where the changes are.  We can add other joins and predicates (conditions), I'd follow the same pattern, If we need a `WHERE` clause, we'd add that immediately before the `ORDER BY`. For performance, we'd also repeat a predicate on `item_histories` in the outer query in the inline view query `r`)

Comment: Exactly what I want, thank you very much! I would upvote but I only have 13 rep at the moment.

Comment: @JoshuaF: I upvoted your question; your question was very well presented. Sample data, expected resultset and what you've attempted so far. Sorry I couldn't/can't help with the Sequelize... I'm not familiar with that. When I work with interfaces like that, I mostly just get frustrated that I can't write the SQL I want to run. For our applications, we use iBatis (myBatis), which has us writing native SQL for the most part. (iBatis adds features for bind placeholders, and some dynamic SQL generation (we use that a lot for variable IN list contents)

Comment: Thank you very much, I also voted your answer since I'm able to now. Sequelize doesn't seem to support subqueries like that but it does have a way to run raw queries so it works fine, thanks again. Any suggestions on a better title so people can Google it?